# Wipe Data on Locked Phone Stuck in Boot Loop without Recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, fastboot, bootloader-lock, nexus-5x

I am returning a Project Fi Nexus-5X device that went into a boot loop but want to wipe all my data off it before shipping it back to Google Fi.

However:

- the device is oem locked
- any fastboot erase (`fastboot erase userdata`, `fastboot -w`, etc) says I cannot do so until the device is unlocked
- `fastboot flashing unlock` states oem unlock is not allowed
- I can't enter recovery mode - doing so from fastboot mode immediately restarts the device, back to the black "Google" screen - and into the boot loop again
- I can temporarily enter Download Mode, but the device restarts after about 10 seconds

So I'm not sure of any way to wipe my data at this point.

Comment: Can I recommend [baking your 5X](http://dev-with-alex.blogspot.com/2016/12/oven-fresh-phone.html) to try to get it to temporarily turn back on?

Comment: Note: I have no idea if this is actually safe, and assume no responsibility at all!

Comment: @owlswipe Holy ____, that's actually a thing... Blows my mind